# Function will NOT execute the return statement in PHP

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, return

Good day fellow programmers! For some weird reason the function will not return anything after the first query is executed. I noticed the `$error` variable was not being returned and after checking I noticed nothing would be returned after the first query is executed. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
public function store_review(){
  $this->load->database();
  $error = NULL;

  $title = $this->input->post('title');   
  $raiting = $this->input->post('raiting');
  $description = $this->input->post('description');

  //Insert review
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO reviews (title, raiting) VALUES (?, ?)", array($title, $raiting));    

  if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
    $reviewID = $this->db->insert_id();

    //If review inserted insert description             
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO reviews_descriptions (review_id, description) VALUES (?, ?)", array($reviewID, $description));

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1){
      $error = 'Could not insert review description.';
    }           
  } 
  else {
    //If review could not be inserted duplicate exists
    $error = 'Review already exists.';
  }

  //THE FUNCTION WILL NOT EXECUTE ANY RETURNS AFTER THE FIRST QUERY
  return $error;
}
```

NOTE: I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: please show how you are running `store_review` and checking on the return value

Comment: $error = $this->model->store_review();
    if(isset($error)) echo 'error is set';

Answer (score 0):

Here is the catch:

```
 $error = NULL;
```

when you assign `NULL` to `$error` it makes $error a set variable, eventhough it is null.

Thus the following line would give you unexpected result:

```
$error = $this->model->store_review(); if(isset($error)) echo 'error is set';
```

The proper way to check would be to use [is_null](http://www.php.net/is_null)

---

Here is how you can test my answer

```
<?php

$error = NULL;

if(is_null($error)){

echo "is_null | error not set \n";
}else{

echo "is_null |error set \n";
}


if(isset($error)){

echo "isset | error not set \n";
}else{

echo "isset |error set \n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
is_null | error not set 
isset   | error set
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/108834)</kbd>

Comment: I thank you for that but it still doesn't work, again, nothing is being returned! If instead of $error I return something else and try to check what it is there is nothing... at all... Like I said, after the first query return statements don't seem to work with any kind of data.

Comment: @stacker is your insert query successful

Comment: Yes the query inserts data but if it doesn't insert it, it should store the error in the variable and return it. Problem is it never returns anything, not because of the value in the variable but because the return statement won't execute.